# Sorting a file in ascending order

Tags: python, file, sorting

I was given a file with one name per line in random order **myInput01.txt** and I need to order it in ascending order and output the ordered names *one name per line* to a file named **myOutput01.txt**.

```
myhandle = open('myInput01.txt', 'r')  
aLine = myhandle.readlines()  
sorted(aLine)  
aLine = myOutput01.txt  
print myOutput01.txt
```

Comment: Any particular error in the code that you have (assumingly) already developed?

Comment: can you edit the question to add that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future visitors, the easiest and most concise way of doing this in Python (assuming a sort isn't going to blow your system memory) is:

```
with open('myInput01.txt') as fin, open('myOutput01.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(sorted(fin))
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this part is ok:

```
myhandle = open('myInput01.txt', 'r')  
aLine = myhandle.readlines()
```

You open a file (get a file handler in `myhandle`) and read its lines into `aLine`.

Now, there's a problem with:

```
sorted(aLine)
```

The `sorted` function doesn't do anything to the `aLine` argument. It returns a sorted new list. So it's either you use `aLine.sort()` to sort in-place  or assign the output of the `sorted` function to another variable:

```
   sorted_lines = sorted(aLine)
```

Take a look to [this sorting tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Also, these two lines are very problematic:

```
aLine = myOutput01.txt  
print myOutput01.txt
```

You're overwriting your `aLine` variable with something called `myOutput01.txt`, which is unknown to the script (what is it? where is it defined?). You need to proceed in a similar way as to read a file. You need to open a handler and write *stuff* to the file using that handler as a reference.

You need:

```
   mywritehandle = open('myOutputO1.txt', 'w')
   mywritehandle.writelines(sorted_lines)
   mywritehandle.close()
```

Or, to avoid having to call `close()` explicitly:

```
with open('myOutputO1.txt', 'w') as mywritehandle:
    mywritehandle.writelines(sorted_lines)
```

You should familiarize yourself with [file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and be aware that `myOutput01.txt` is very different to `"myOutput01.txt"`.

Comment: They do have a `.writelines` - so `mywritehandle.writelines(sorted(myhandle))` is fine - no need for the `.readlines` etc...

Comment: Just do away with `aLine` as `sorted` will return a sorted list from an iterable (and file handles are iterable), also note that `aLine` won't be sorted as `sorted(aLine)` will create a sorted list leaving `aLine` unchanged, then just discard the list... literally the only line you need is in the above comment

Comment: Yeah, that I knew, and that's why I mentioned `sort` and linked the sorting tutorial, but I usually don't like deviating too much from the initial OP's code (IMHO, it could do more harm than good)

Comment: Okay - just mentioning it as *...and then use sorted to sort those lines in order. It's good...* is somewhat misleading as `sorted(aLine)` is not good - it's not doing anything useful :p

Comment: Oh dang! I got `sort` and `sorted` mixed up!... Editing now... That's why you have 52k rep and I have 2.8k **:-)**

Comment: I've added an answer for future visitors - but I like this one as you're actually explaining stuff rather than just providing a code only answer +1

Comment: I saw **:-)** (and I'm pretty sure the upvote was you **;-)** ). I like coding... That's why I like explaining stuff (sometimes not too successfully, as you made me see). Thanks! I learned something too, thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
outputFile = open('myOutput01.txt','w')
inputFile = open('myInput01.txt','r')
content = inputFile.readlines()
for name in sorted(content):
    outputFile.write(name + '\n')
inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```